Questions For the Expansion of Gravitational Waves
In the appendix B of this paper for effective field theory of gravitational waves, they expand the metric perturbation:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$$
here deviation $h$ is dimensionless. However, later in the expansion of point particle action $S = -m\int{d\tau}$:
$$S_{\text{pp}} = -\frac{m}{2M_{\text{PL}}}\int{dx_{0}\,}\int_{\mathbf{k}}e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}(x_{0})}H_{\mathbf{k}00}(x_0)+\cdots\tag{B8}$$
where $m$ is the particle mass, $M_{\text{PL}}$ is the Plank scale, and $H_{\mathbf{k}00}$ is the $00$ component of potential mode of deviation $h \equiv \bar{h} + H$, and the appearance of Plank scale in the expansion make me confused, it seems that they've used the metric perturbation:
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + \frac{1}{M_{\text{PL}}}h_{\mu\nu}$$
instead of the original one.
Can anyone clarify it? I know the first choice of metric perturbation is better in the analysis of power counting $L$ in appendix A, but I think in the rest of the paper, they've used the second one.

Normalizing $h$ as in $h/M_{\rm Pl}$ has the effect that when you expand the Einstein-Hilbert action
$$
S = \frac{M_{\rm Pl}^2}{2}\int d^4 x \sqrt{-g} R
$$
the kinetic term for $h$ is canonically normalized. Or, in other words, this scaling lets us put the action in a standard form where the coefficient of the kinetic term is $-1/2$, which is the usual starting point for derivations in effective field theory. Schematically,
$$
S = \int d^4 x \left(-\frac{1}{2} (\partial h)^2 + \frac{1}{M_{\rm Pl}} h (\partial h)^2 + \cdots\right)
$$
Note that here, $h$ has dimensions of mass, like we typically expect for a bosonic field.
As a result, we can use normal power counting theorems and intuition from effective field theory. For example, we see here that $h (\partial h)^2$ is a dimension-5 operator coming at scale $M_{\rm Pl}$. If the kinetic term had a very large or small coefficient, or if $h$ was normalized in a way where it didn't have dimensions of mass, we wouldn't be able to directly apply normal effective field theory arguments to the action.
